How to ensure last step of two tests running in parallel execute at once/same time in PlayWright
Lately, we have come across an issue in our application, where two users filled in the form details and clicked submit to find summary with information swapped. I am looking to simulate the scenario where two PlayWright tests run parallel but the last step/action execute at once.

test.describe.configure({mode: 'parallel'})

test('first test', async({})=>{
step1..
step2..
step3..
step4..
})

test('second test', async({})=>{
step1..
step2..
step3..
step4..
step5..
})


I run the script in parallel with two workers i.e., 'npx playwright test --workers=2' command. I want to ensure 'first test-step4' and 'second test-step5' are executed at the same time.
I have tried below workers api documentation but found no luck. From my research, I think nodejs 'worker threads' and events may be helpful. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-worker#worker-evaluate

This is a rather odd thing to want to do. Why do you want this exactly? There might be a much better way to achieve whatever your underlying goal is if you don't mind providing a bit of context. Thanks.

@ggorlen Thank you for the reply. I am trying to do this to stimulate a real time issue that happened recently where two users clicked on a button (after filling the form) to find modal displaying incorrect i.e., swapped information. Hence, in my given tests, I would like to execute 'first test->step4' and 'second test->step5' at once which will be equivalent to two users clicking the button at once. The other solution, I am thinking is controlling the execution between the two tests such that the last step in each test runs at the same time. I am open to any other ideas for this.

Thanks for the context. Why not click the button twice at once in the same test? As far as I know, there's no way to guarantee that run two steps run simultaneously, nor would that be desirable, since the behavior you're discussing is a single test case.

Yes, this is a single test case, however run with two different users as two separate playwright tests. Hence, clicking the button twice at once in a test wouldn't suffice the need. The button from the two separate tests needs to be clicked at once.

Why can't two users be active in the same test on two different pages? That makes more sense than trying to get two different tests to run at the same time--you can actually guarantee the buttons fire as close as possible at the same time on two different browser sessions. await Promise.all([page1.locator("button").click(), page2.locator("button").click()]). If you provide a [mcve] it'd be a lot easier to provide a working answer. Maybe simplify the problem a bit for the purposes of the question and make a sample page that needs to be automated similarly to your actual use case.

@ggorlen thank you for the guidance. I think different pages within a same test accomponied by promise can work. I will try it out.

Sounds good, feel free to post a self answer if you figure it out.
